# How to set classpath from a config file for a Java application

Tags: java, classpath

Hi, I am developing an application in *Java*. I have to run that jar in different Operating Systems, such as *winxp*, *linux*, *rhel*, *Ubuntu*.

I have some jar files that must be in the classpath.

The client is not ready to set the path, so I have to set it programmatically.

My problem is with the different Operating Systems, because the user will have different paths. How can I get the path through a config file?

How do I manage OS and these dependencies?

Any idea if I can set the path at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You should package all the jars your program depends inside your executable jar. In your project create lib directory and push all the dependencies inside. This will save you lot of pain.

If you use Maven2 , you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) in your pom.xml. 
In case you build from IDE (Eclipse or IntelliJ etc) you can use the wizard: R.click your project root -> Export -> Runnable JAR etc .

Comment: I required some flexibility for changing current jar

Comment: can u explain about Maven2 i havent used it.

Comment: You need no flexibility: java is multi-platform and your jars are packed inside, remember? Google for maven2.